# consistency of MLE estimator example

Tags: statistics

Given the density function $f(x;\theta)=\theta x^{\theta -1}$ with $\theta \gt 0$ and $x \in (0,1)$, once found the MLE estimator $\hat{\theta}=\frac{-n}{\sum{\log{X_i}}}$ i want to show the consistency of such an estimator. I was suggested to apply the strong law of large numbers, although i am not sure how. Should I first obtain the expected value of the random variable $\log(X_i)$ and then apply the SLLN on them or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not familiar with SLLN, there are several other ways to approach the  problem,

1. **The simplest**: a property of ML Estimators is that **they are consistent**.
2. Consistency you have to prove is $\hat{\theta}\xrightarrow{\mathcal{P}}\theta$

So first let's calculate the density of the estimator.

Observe that (it is very easy to prove this with the fundamental transformation theorem)

$$Y=-logX\sim Exp(\theta)$$

Thus $W=\Sigma_iY_i\sim Gamma(n;\theta)$ and $\frac{1}{W}\sim \text{Inverse Gamma}$ and consequently

$$\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}]=\frac{n}{n-1}\theta$$

$$\mathbb{V}[\hat{\theta}]=\frac{n^2}{(n-1)^2(n-2)}\theta$$

This grant the following are both true

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}]=\theta$$

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{V}[\hat{\theta}]=0$$

This is an IFF condition for the convergence in $L^2$ which implies also the convergence in probability (the consistency of your estimator)

3. Calculate the convergence in probability by the definition

Using 2 is a better way because you proved also the convergence in quadratic mean, that it is stronger

---

Trying all the method we showed is an useful exercise (IMHO)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Regarding 1, can it be proved that every MLE is consistent?

Comment: @MattiaMariantoni : Yes, of course! Actually in the basic courses this and other interesting properties of ML estimators are only given without proof. You can find the theorem (Th 10.1.6) and a sketch of the proof in Casella Berger. Details of the proof can be found, for example, in Stuart, Ord and Arnold - 1999,  - Advanced Theory of Statistics, Chapter 18

Answer (score 1):

You can show that $Y = -\ln X \sim Exp(\theta)$, hence $\mathbb{E}[Y]=1/\theta$, thus by the SLLN and the continuous mapping theorem
$$
\hat{\theta}_n \xrightarrow{a.s.} (1/\theta)^{-1} = \theta, 
$$
as $n \to \infty$.